# Prove that if a set H has only one limit point, then it is countable.

Tags: analysis, limits

Unfortunately i don't even know how to start with this problem.
Edit: H is a subset of real numbers.

Comment: You need to provide more context for this.  Is $H$ a subset of real numbers, or of a general topological space?

Comment: As written (in such generality), this isn't true. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. It has no limit points, but is uncountable. It's likely you mean as points in an interval, or perhaps region, of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably this is a set of real numbers with the usual topology.

Hint: if $L$ is the limit point, how many members of your set can be in $(L-2\epsilon, L-\epsilon) \cup (L+\epsilon, L+2\epsilon)$?

Comment: I assume that $(L-2\epsilon, L-\epsilon) \cup (L+\epsilon, L+2\epsilon)$ is supposed to be countable, and then we can use the fact that the union of countable many countable sets is also countable. I am not sure why this set should be countable.

Comment: How about the union of the above sets with $\epsilon = 1/(2n)$?

Comment: I think i got it: $(L-2\epsilon, L-\epsilon) \cup (L+\epsilon, L+2\epsilon)$
has to be finite, because it is a bounded set with no limit points.
There is a theorem stating that if a set is infinite and bounded, it has a limit point. If a set is bounded and infinite, then there is always a monotone bounded series in it, which means it is convergent. If it is convergent, then the limit is the set's limit point.